Group by everything before a character in a string
I have a data frame with three different columns: Wavelength, Sample, and Mean.
Wavelength <- c(400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400)
Sample <- c("A.1", "A.2", "A.3", "AB.1", "AB.2", "AB.3")
Mean <- c(0.434, 0.347, 0.434, 0.674, 0.591, 0.857)
df <- data.frame(Wavelength, Sample, Mean)
df
  Wavelength Sample   Mean
1        400    A.1  0.434
2        400    A.2  0.347
3        400    A.3  0.434
4        400   AB.1  0.674
5        400   AB.2  0.591
6        400   AB.3  0.857

Is there a way to group by everything before the "." in the sample column, and then put those rows into a separate data frame? An example of what I am looking for is like this:
>df
  Wavelength Sample   Mean
1        400    A.1  0.434
2        400    A.2  0.347
3        400    A.3  0.434
>df1
  Wavelength Sample   Mean
4        400   AB.1  0.674
5        400   AB.2  0.591
6        400   AB.3  0.857

I have more than 2 groups of samples, but these are just an example of what I am trying to do.

split(df, ~sub(".\\d+","", Sample))

setNames(split(df, ~sub("\\d+","", Sample)), paste0("df", seq(unique(sub("\\d+","", df$Sample)))))|>list2env(.GlobalEnv)

@Onyambu Care to post an answer?

@Onyambu in my actual data, some groups have numbers before the "." as well, how do I make sure those are included?

@Keegan simply use "\\.\\d+$" as the pattern

split(df, ~sub("\\.\\d+$","", Sample))

$A
  Wavelength Sample  Mean
1        400    A.1 0.434
2        400    A.2 0.347
3        400    A.3 0.434

$AB
  Wavelength Sample  Mean
4        400   AB.1 0.674
5        400   AB.2 0.591
6        400   AB.3 0.857


If you're working in the tidyverse you can use group_split() from the dplyr package:
library(dplyr)

df |>
  group_split(grp = sub("\\..*$", "", Sample))

Output
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Wavelength Sample  Mean grp  
       <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
1        400 A.1    0.434 A    
2        400 A.2    0.347 A    
3        400 A.3    0.434 A    

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Wavelength Sample  Mean grp  
       <dbl> <chr>  <dbl> <chr>
1        400 AB.1   0.674 AB   
2        400 AB.2   0.591 AB   
3        400 AB.3   0.857 AB   


Begin with strsplit.
df$SampLetter <- sapply(strsplit(x = df$Sample, split='\\.'), head, 1)

Gives:
> df
  Wavelength Sample  Mean SampLetter
1        400    A.1 0.434          A
2        400    A.2 0.347          A
3        400    A.3 0.434          A
4        400   AB.1 0.674         AB
5        400   AB.2 0.591         AB
6        400   AB.3 0.857         AB

You can then split(df, ~SampLetter).

Something like might be useful:
Wavelength <- c(400, 400, 400, 400, 400, 400)
Sample <- c("A.1", "A.2", "A.3", "AB.1", "AB.2", "234AB.3")
Mean <- c(0.434, 0.347, 0.434, 0.674, 0.591, 0.857)
df <- data.frame(Wavelength, Sample, Mean)

df |>
  dplyr::mutate(ala = sub("\\.(.)*", "", Sample)) |>
  dplyr::group_by(ala) |>
  dplyr::count()
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#> # Groups:   ala [3]
#>   ala       n
#>   <chr> <int>
#> 1 234AB     1
#> 2 A         3
#> 3 AB        2

Created on 2024-06-06 with reprex v2.1.0
